# Windows Mobile 5/6 Bluetooth Connection

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

Good day Sir, Im working on a project using a windows mobile PDA to Monitor ECG heart waves and vital signs from bluetooth devices on a patient.

Im trying to decide which bluetooth SDK to use to simplify and setup searching and connecting to these bluetooth devices. One such device is a mini USB heart monitoring device. Im using C# as it seems easier. With your In the Hand option, from 32feet, is there a manual or tutorial i could use.?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a report titled "Small wireless ECG with Bluetooth Communication to a PDA". Maybe you'll find something of interest inside. It's [here](http://www.idt.mdh.se/utbildning/exjobb/files/TR0479.pdf).